# Unbind multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bind() for multiple functions. My problem is how do I unbind them using a `$(document).mouseup(function(e)`?

```
$('#aaa').mousedown(function(e) {
  $(document).bind('mousemove.rImg', function(e2) {
    rotateOnMouse(e2, '#lt_');
  });
});

$('#bbb').mousedown(function(e3) {
  $(document).bind('mousemove.rTxt', function(e2) {
    rotateOnMoust(e2, '#fW_');
  });
});
```

How can I do the unbind for the above?

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  $(document).unbind('mousemove.rImg');
  $(document).unbind('mousemove.rTxt');
});
```

Comment: It seems you have the answer already.

Comment: @Sacho thanks. But that doesn't work for me?

Comment: don't use `bind` use `on` and `off`

Comment: Why nested event handlers? Bad idea!

Comment: @Vohuman thanks :) Can you show the better way?

Comment: Can't really reproduce your problem - http://jsfiddle.net/hoo80a5e/ - what makes you think your code doesn't work?

Comment: @Sacho: doesn't unbind.I'm not getting any errors either.

Comment: `$(document).off('mousemove.rImg mousemove.rTxt')` - you can add multiple events inside the method. Nothing wrong with nested events handlers if you unbind properly by the way. Passing an event parameter `(e)` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Beki Like I demonstrate in the jsfiddle, your code *does* unbind the mousemove handlers. You'll have to provide more information if you want to get to the bottom of your issue.

Comment: @Sacho ` $(document).unbind('mousemove.rTxt'); ` doesn't unbind if `$(document).unbind('mousemove.rImg');` is not present.

Comment: Still can't reproduce your problem at all(none of the things you're listing as problems are present in the fiddle I posted) - try constructing an example on jsfiddle to illustrate it.

Comment: Why don't you bind the mousemove to the current element and do a general unbind then, @Beki? Showing some more of the relevant code might be useful.

Comment: Excellent, glad I threw it out there then. :-)